# Low validation accuracy in parallel DenseNet

Tags: deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I've taken the code from https://github.com/flyyufelix/cnn_finetune and remodeled it so that there is now two DenseNet-121 in parallel, with the layers after each model's last Global Average Pooled removed.

Both models were joined together like this:

```
print("Begin model 1")
    model = densenet121_model(img_rows=img_rows, img_cols=img_cols, color_type=channel, num_classes=num_classes)
    print("Begin model 2")
    model2 = densenet121_nw_model(img_rows=img_rows, img_cols=img_cols, color_type=channel, num_classes=num_classes)

    mergedOut = Add()([model.output,model2.output])
    #mergedOut = Flatten()(mergedOut)    
    mergedOut = Dense(num_classes, name='cmb_fc6')(mergedOut)
    mergedOut = Activation('softmax', name='cmb_prob')(mergedOut)

    newModel = Model([model.input,model2.input], mergedOut)

    adam = Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-6, amsgrad=True)
    newModel.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    # Start Fine-tuning
    newModel.fit([X_train,X_train], Y_train,
              batch_size=batch_size,
              nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
              shuffle=True,
              verbose=1,
              validation_data=([X_valid,X_valid],Y_valid)
              )
```

The first model has its layers frozen, and the one in parallel is suppose to learn additional features on top of the first model to supposedly improve accuracy.

However, even at 100 epochs,
the training accuracy is almost 100% but validation floats around 9%.

I'm not quite sure what could be the reason and how to fix it, considering I've already changed the optimizer from SGD (same concept, 2 densenets with the first trained on ImageNet, the second has no weights to begin with same results) to Adam (2 densenets, both pre-trained on imagenet).

```
Epoch 101/1000
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1678s 2s/step - loss: 0.0550 - acc: 0.9820 - val_loss: 12.9906 - val_acc: 0.0900
Epoch 102/1000
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1703s 2s/step - loss: 0.0567 - acc: 0.9880 - val_loss: 12.9804 - val_acc: 0.1100
```